# WPF: ErrorMessage when trying to Bind a Line to two UIElements

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, uielement

Im trying to bind a Line to two ScatterViewItems:

```
private void BindLineToScatterViewItems(Shape line, ScatterViewItem origin, ScatterViewItem destination)
        {
            // Bind line.(X1,Y1) to origin.ActualCenter
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.X1Property, new Binding { Source = origin, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.X") });
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.Y1Property, new Binding { Source = origin, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.Y") });

            // Bind line.(X2,Y2) to destination.ActualCenter
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.X2Property, new Binding { Source = destination, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.X") });
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.Y2Property, new Binding { Source = destination, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.Y") });
        }
```

But I always get the following error message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value
>   produced by BindingExpression is not
>   valid for target property.;
>   Value='NaN'
>   BindingExpression:Path=ActualCenter.X;
>   DataItem='ScatterViewItem' (Name='');
>   target element is 'Line' (Name='');
>   target property is 'X1' (type
>   'Double')

Nevertheless it is working, but how can I surpress this warning? And why is this warning displayed?

EDIT: According to the answer below, I use now following converter, but still get the errors:

```
public class NormalizationConverter : IValueConverter

    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
           return (double) value == double.NaN ? Binding.DoNothing : (double) value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Surface but apparently `ActualCenter.X` and `ActualCenter.Y` start out as `double.NaN` before they are assigned their actual values.  Since this doesn't last long, you could you any other double value instead.  So to avoid the warning, you can use a converter that translates `double.NaN` to `O`:

```
public class NormalizationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var doubleValue = (double)value;
        return doubleValue == double.NaN ? 0 : doubleValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm partial to using Binding.DoNothing in such cases.

Comment: You can use `return doubleValue == double.NaN ? Binding.DoNothing : doubleValue;`.

Comment: @Rick Sladkey I edited my question since i still get the errors

Comment: Because I'm not running Surface I cannot test it.  Try putting a breakpoint in the converter to make sure it is being called.